# useFakeTimers no longer works with jest 27.5.1

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app, enzyme, sinon

I have been struggling for about 2 weeks to understand why our projects test are failing after upgrading our CRA to react-scripts v5(webpack 5). Let me give you more details. Our application recently got upgraded to Node18 and since node18 needs webpack5, we had to upgrade this as well. This is React app that was created with create-react-app. New CRA came with new jest 27.5.1(used to be 24.9.0). I tried to downgrade jest to the older version but since this is create-react-app, i was not able to. A lot of tests are involved jest.useFakeTimers() which is runs from beforeEach() clause. I am fully aware of changes that jest was undergone in v27. I tried to use jest.useFakeTimers("legacy") and jest.useRealTimers() as well, this is still not working. So basically what happens is the test is just hanging, it is not failing or passing, just hanging and not running at all. I debugged it and this is definitely jest.useFakeTimers() since if i disable it test goes through and fails.
the test is the following:

```
beforeEach(()=>{ jest.useFakeTimers("legacy"); } it("Shows modal window", done=>{ let modal = getModal(); // returns wrapper for modal window(enzyme library) expect(modal.props().open).toBe(false); // this is passing jest.advanceTimersByTime(60*1000); // this line is unreachable it gets stuck in jest.useFakeTimers() })
```

There is another issue(I am pretty sure related to similar thing). When I am trying to spyOn window methods like setTimeout, postMessage, setImmediate etc. It does not seem to work either. Also: Since the project was running on jasmine2 and it does not work in jest27, i had to add this explicitly as "testRunner": "jasmine2".

Do you have any suggestions for me, I tried to search everywhere and it seems I cannot find the answer? I would really appreciate your help. If you need more information I will gladly provide you with.

I tried to use jest.useFakeTimers with "legacy" and "modern" arguments. I also used sinon library which jest27 I believe uses under the hood in v27. I am not sure how to resolve this at this moment